# using oslogin on gcp with osAdminLogin role a user can't sudo on the instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have some GCP users with the roles : 
* compute.instances.osAdminLogin
* iam.serviceAccountUser

They connect throw ssh with the GCP web interface in compute engine

When they do sudo ls

For some user the password is requested and some not.

in the folder /var/google-sudoers.d/
for the users that can do sudo without the prompt we can read on their file:

```
user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

for the others the files are empty

os information :

```
uname -a
Linux xxx 4.15.0-1027-gcp #28~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 18 10:10:51 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For the same users, on another vm, in the same gcp project, they all can do sudo.

I am expecting that for all users having the same roles, they have the same sudo behaviour on instances.

What should I do for my users to be able to sudo ? ( except overriding the empty files in the folder  /var/google-sudoers.d/ > that is working but may not be stable)

Comment: It could be due to multiple reason. I would suggest to create a public issue tracker [https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers] and provide the reproduction steps so that we can reproduce and investigate in details.

Comment: If you reboot the problem instance, does the problem remain? Are you using an orginization? At what level are your granting osAdminLogin (instance, project, organization)? If you remove `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` from the instance and then add the role back, does this fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem on a project that was originally set up with the legacy login system (based on SSH keys stored in instance or project metadata). When I converted the project to use OS Login, I lost the ability to sudo without a password on one VM instance. This was a major problem, since I had never set a password for my user account, and therefore was unable to sudo to troubleshoot the problem.

Things I tried that did NOT work:

- Rebooting the instance
- Explicitly adding role `roles/compute.osAdminLogin` to my IAM account (I was already a project owner)

I solved the problem by [editing the project compute engine metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) to disable OS Login. After disabling, I confirmed that I was able to log into the problematic instance and sudo without a password. I then edited the project metadata again to re-enable OS Login. This time, passwordless sudo worked on the problematic instance. It appears that the instance was not fully reconfigured the first time I switched from legacy login to OS Login.

Comment: I think it was in the use case that you describe. My vm instance was originally set up as legacy login as you said. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @GaëlStéphant You're welcome. If my answer helped, please vote up and/or mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

We recently ran into this issue when adding "enable-oslogin=true" to already existing vm's in GCP.  We found that if we set enable-oslogin=false on the vm, we could still sudo, but when re-enabling oslogin we sometimes could not.   We also tried to add the enable-oslogin=true key to the project data and that didn't seem to make a difference.  Rebooting the vm's made no difference.

Here's what worked in our case.   If you have been logging into a vm with oslogin disabled, then an entry gets created in the /etc/passwd file.  If you enable oslogin and the userid is the same as before,  then no files for the user get created in the /var/google-user.d or /var/google-sudoers.d directories.

To fix this, we:

1. Deleted the user using `userdel <username>`  which deleted the /etc/password entry.
2. Re-enabled oslogin
3. Used gcloud compute ssh ( or cloudshell ) to login. Entries were created in the /var/google-* directories at this point.
4. Used `sudo -l` to verify sudo permissions.